# phonegap navigator.app.loadUrl error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, navigator

i'm trying use navigator.app.loadUrl in deviceready problem cannot call method loadURL, and this my script index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.apps = {
    loadURL : function(url){
        navigator.app.loadUrl('file:///android_asset/www/' + url);
        return false;       
    },
    callBack : function(){
        //code disini
    },
    saveStorage: function(name,val){
        window.localStorage.setItem(name,val);
        return false;
    },
    getStorage: function(name){
        window.localStorage.getItem(name);
    }

};
</script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), true);
    }

    function onDeviceReady(){

         doInit();
    }

    function doInit(){
        apps.loadURL('index.html');
    }


    </script>;
```

and then myactivity.java

```
package com.example.learyphonegap;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
        super.setStringProperty("errorUrl", "file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

i have googling for the problem and not find this same problem

Comment: Show your mainactivity.java code..

Comment: myactivity have ben include on posting, please check mr. vick... thk

Comment: is above code your index.html page?

Comment: Does your deviceready event loads? Try with an alert box.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with openExternal is true

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true });
```

Comment: I've tried with navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true }); but still warning error cannot load method loadUrl

Comment: post error message or logcat message. Am trying your code works but deviceready call loadUrl to load index.html again index.html calls device ready. It's like recursive call unable to stop the process. And I want to know what purpose your working that code.

Comment: thank all for help and suporting, and then script loadUrl is work on emulator,thank u